# Initiative Login AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, federated-identity, amazon-iam

Can we do initiative login in AWS. I am using IDP(Identity Provider) to access AWS Console. it means Authentication will be done by my IDP and according to that i'll provide the access on AWS Console, So my question is Suppose if user directly hit the AWS Login Link, Then can be redirect him to our IDP login page.
Can we do Initiative Login in AWS ?

Comment: No, i am asking like suppose if i hit the AWS global URL to login and enter my company ID to login, so By checking my Company ID as a prefix it can auto-redirect to my IDP Login page ?

Comment: I don't think its possible, but, I'll revisit this page.

Comment: Ya please if Possible